# How to get specific word from the string column using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table.

```
create table tblProduct
(
    ProductID int primary key identity(1000,1),
    ProductName varchar(100),
    ProductDescription nvarchar(max)
)
```

In this table, there are 1000 records like this...

```
ProductID=1001  
ProductName='Apple i6'  
ProductDescription='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. **Product of USA** Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'

ProductID=1002  
ProductName='Micromax Canvas'  
ProductDescription='Scrambled it to make a type specimen bookLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. **Product of INDIA** Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'

ProductID=1003  
ProductName='Oppo Z3'  
ProductDescription='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. **Product of INDIA** Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'
```

and so on....

Now I want to find only country name (no duplicate and no other word) from the `productDescription` column of the `tblProduct`...

Output must be something like this:

```
Country Name - Total(Group By)  
USA - 1  
INDIA - 2
```

Note: "product of XXX*" will be available almost all rows of `productdescription` column.

*xxx is the country name.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes!! select productdescription from tblproduct where productdescription like 'Product of'

Comment: that's close, but you're missing the `%` wildcards. Also, while that will work, it's not the most efficient way to do this. Look into FULL-TEXT indexing.

Comment: sorry!! select productdescription from tblproduct where productdescription like '%Product of%'.........but it returns me complete value of description column..

Answer (score 2):

You can use string manipulation functions `LEFT/RIGHT/PATINDEX`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
   r = RIGHT(ProductDescription, LEN(ProductDescription) -  
                               PATINDEX('%Product of%' ,ProductDescription) - 10)
  FROM #tblProduct
  WHERE PATINDEX('%Product of%' ,ProductDescription) > 0
)
SELECT country = LEFT(r, CHARINDEX(' ', r)-1), COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM cte
GROUP BY LEFT(r, CHARINDEX(' ', r)-1);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/391756)**</kbd>

But you have to think about corner cases:

- country name contains multiple words like `Russian Federation`
- what with multiple names (`U.S./USA/United States of America...`) you will get multiple groups, you need data cleansing

> Note: "product of XXX*" will be available almost all rows of
>   productdescription column.

If you know all countries in advance it will be much easier. Just create table countries:

```
name      master 
'U.S.'    'USA'
'USA'     'USA'
'India'   'India'

SELECT c.master, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM #tblProduct p
JOIN countries c
  ON p.Description LIKE '%Product of ' + c.name + '%'
GROUP BY c.master;
```

**EDIT:**

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT r = RIGHT(ProductDescription, LEN(ProductDescription) -  PATINDEX('%Product of <strong>%' ,ProductDescription) - 18)
FROM #tblProduct
WHERE PATINDEX('%Product of <strong>%' ,ProductDescription) > 0
)
SELECT country = LEFT(r, CHARINDEX('<', r)-1), COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM cte
GROUP BY r,LEFT(r, CHARINDEX('<', r)-1);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/391770)**</kbd>

Comment: actually the full syntax like that <li><i>Product of <strong>India</strong></i></li>....can we get country name from this syntax I mean between <strong></strong>tag by your code??...Yes..you are right..country name can be multipal words....

Comment: @user3786581 Yes we can, can't you post this in first place?

Comment: can't you post this in first place...what u mean..Sir??

Comment: @user3786581 This means that this kind of information should be added in original question.

Comment: Actually...When I asked this question I have no idea about this type of query can be occurred like you told me......So Sir please tell me how can we get exact country name from my synax ..by the way I also try something like this SELECT distinct SUBSTRING([Description], CHARINDEX('<li><i>Product of <strong>', [Description])
, CHARINDEX('</strong></i></li>',[Description]) - CHARINDEX('<li><i>Product of <strong>', [Description]) + Len('</strong></i></li>'))
from tblproduct where description like '%<li><i>Product of%' but I think your query performance and method is good compare to my solution.

Comment: @user3786581 Do you have only one `<strong>` pari in entire text?

Comment: No Sir!! It can be many like  <ul>
            <li>xxx</li>
            <li>Brand Name : <strong></strong></li>
            <li>Weight : <strong>000</strong></li>
            <li><i>Product of <strong>India</strong></i></li>
            <li>Gender : </li>
            <li>Formulation : </li>
          
        </ul> <ul>
        
            <li>Feature 2  : <strong></strong></li>
            <li><i>Feature 4 <strong>India</strong></i></li>
          
         
        </ul>...somehing like this I mean to say in ProductDescription column many <ul>,<li><strong>  and other html tag can be ....