# Extract words from string to suggest using pattern matching

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have 3 columns in SQL "Details", "Keywords", and "Name" with MAX Langth.
and table have 1000 of rows.

I want, When I will start to type words in text box it will be search in above fileds and all records of table and get words from above fields which are matches  (not only all exact matches but also words which started from typed words.)

ex; there are following lines in database:

1. This is automatic machine.
2. That is macho man.
3. This is use less machine.
4. A Mach number is a measure of airspeed, and not of ground speed.
5. These machine are very use full.
6. Machine assembly.

Then if I type word in text box "Mach" then following words should be fetched to suggest:

1. **Machine**
2. **macho**
3. **Mach**

And If I type words in text box "Machine a" Then following words should be fetched to suggest:

1. **machine are**
2. **Machine assembly**

The code I tried

```
plist = productlist.Where(s => s.ProductName.Contains(searchKeyword) || 
                      s.Keywords.Contains(searchKeyword) || 
                      s.ProductDescription.Contains(searchKeyword) || 
                      s.AditionalInfo.Contains(searchKeyword));
```

What is appropriate method to achieve same thing in asp.net.

Please suggest.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have fetched records which contain typed words, But I want words instead of records.   I have used below code:-                       productlist = productlist.Where(s => s.ProductName.Contains(searchKeyword) || s.Keywords.Contains(searchKeyword) || s.ProductDescription.Contains(searchKeyword) || s.AditionalInfo.Contains(searchKeyword));

Comment: You can use string manipulation functions LEFT/RIGHT/PATINDEX Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33702138/795683

Comment: Try using Linq and Regex.

Comment: I dont want to use SQL procedure, I can use only Linq statments and REGX, could you please help, how can I achieve same result.